# Spying on factory which uses $http get to use to check function is callled

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, factory

I have written a factory which uses the $http get method to retrieve the json data. Now I'm trying to add a unit test for the factory to check whether the function is called or not

This is my factory

```
.factory('dataFactory',function($http){

function getData(){
  var request =  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/data.json'
  });
  return request;
  }
   var service = {
     getData : getData
   };

   return service;
});
```

This is my controller

```
.controller('jsonController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,stringService,dataFactory){

  dataFactory.getData()
  .then(function(response){
    if(response){
      $scope.result = response.data.record;
      console.log(response.data.record);
    } else {
      // empty data message
    }
   })
   .catch(function(error){
    console.log('something went wrong', error);
   });
});
```

This is my Test

```
describe('Testing factory', function() {

beforeEach(module('factories'));
var mySpy;
  mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('service');
  beforeEach(module(function ($provide){
    $provide.value('service',mySpy)
  }));
  describe('get json List', function () {
   it('should return a list', inject(function () {
    spyOn(service, 'getData');
    expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
   }));
 });
});
```

its returning an error:

> service is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

Because you're testing an API / GET return, you DON'T want a Spy! It looks like you're unit test is technically what I would call an "API" or "Integration" Test -- you're checking the data return from an endpoint. (There's nothing wrong with that, but that makes the test setup different).

AngularJS has in its ngMocks a built in service for this called *$httpBacked*.

**Code (spec file)**

```
describe('Testing Darshuu', function() {

    beforeEach(module('Darshuu'));

    // var mySpy;
    var service = null;
    var $httpBackend;

    // Setup Spies in beforeEach() blocks!
    // mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('service');

    beforeEach(module(function($provide){
      // $provide.value('service',mySpy)
      // $provide => manually provide some object or
        // function IN PLACE OF our factory
      // Since we're in a Unit Test for the factory,
      // we actually want to inject it and NOT mock it 
      // completely.
      // See next beforeEach()
    }));

    // _..._ notation for injecting in specs
    beforeEach(inject(function(_dataFactory_, _$httpBackend_) {
      service = _dataFactory_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    /*
      No call is ever made to getData() so this spec
      *should* fail, technically.
    */
    //   describe('get json List', function () {
    //   it('should return a list', inject(function () {
    //     /*
    //       No call is ever made to getData() so this spec
    //       *should* fail, technically.
    //     */
    //     spyOn(service, 'getData');
    //     expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    //   }));
    // });

    describe("DataFactory", function() {

      beforeEach(function() {
        // Since you know to expect an $http request, use the testing 
        // mock for it: $httpBackend
        // THEN, mock the response for the "API".
        // =====
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost/data.json').respond(200, { 
          "test": true,
          "data": [{id:1, name: "Picard"}, {id: 2, name: "Riker"}, {id: 3, name: "Data"}]
        });
      })

      it('HAS a getData() method', function() {
        expect( service.getData ).toBeDefined();
        expect( typeof service.getData ).toEqual("function");
      })

      // BECAUSE there's no AJAX mocking here OR data, it'll fail.
      // I have no idea what your hosting/API is like, but this is
      // a start I hope!
      it("getData() - returns a JSON list (array)", function() {
        service.getData().then(function(response) {
          expect( response.data ).toBeDefined();
          expect( typeof response.data ).toEqual("object");
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
      })
    })

  });
```

**Plnkr**

[Karma+Jasmine Angular Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YWxtjLWBcYtJzVlQXVbG?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Define `factory` as `object` helps you to return methods in your controller as `object function`, for example:

```
app.factory('dataFactory',function($http){
  var factory = {};

  factory.getData = function(){
    var request =  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/data.json'
  });

  return factory;
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("ctrl", function(dataFactory) {
     dataFactory.getData(); //worked
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my controller is working fine and iam getting the object too...but the thing is i need to do unit test for factory to check whether getData() is called or not